# Apache - Redirect HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, https, proxypass

I have the following situation:

An ubuntu server running Webmin with Apache. And I have a static website deployed on it, with SSL already configured.

On the same server I have a standalone application that runs on port 3000, without apache being involved in serving it. The app runs on port 3000 over HTTP but not with HTTPS.

The problem is that my HTTPS website displays the app inside an iframe and can't load it because it runs only on HTTP.

I've tried with ProxyPass, Redirect, and other solutions that I could find, but I'm unexperienced with servers and I can't tell what is the right solution or if it's even possible.

This is what I've tried:

I added inside my conf.ssl file the following:

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPass /app http://server.s2.com:3000/
ProxyPassReverse /app http://server.s2.com:3000/
```

And a lot of other variations.

Also tried this solution:
https://medium.com/tensult/configure-apache-with-node-js-application-on-aws-ubuntu-18-04-server-for-different-http-ports-4e6838c7357f

It somehow redirects to /admin every time, and I end up getting:

```
The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.
```

Comment: A reverse proxy is what you most probably want. Post what you have tried, then we can tell you why it isn't working.

Comment: I added what I've tried. And will look into reverse proxy.

Comment: And what was the error you encountered?

Comment: It redirects to /admin which is not found on the server. I have nothing about admin in my conf files, with or without ssl.

Comment: Most probably you are redirected by your backend server there. If you proxy `/app` to a backend server the baseurl of the backend server usually has to be configured to the same url to generate the proper URLs.